# is it possible for the src of a script to be import?

Tags: vue.js, smtp

I'm trying to use smtp.js to send email however in it's documentation

in order to use it. it has to include the script

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
```

and I'm using setup() in vue.js

```
export default {
setup (){
  return {
}
}
};
```

can I just import the script source? like this

```
import "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found out the answer

need to click the link

and in browser this will show

```
var Email = { send: function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e)
 { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a);
 Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }, ajaxPost: function (e, n, t)
  { var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e); a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), a.onload = function () { var e = a.responseText;
```

so i just put it in the script

```
          <script>
    export default {
    setup() {

    i put it here
and add it to a function
    return{
    }
    }}
    </script>
```

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful if you were to clean up the white space and alignment.

Answer (score 0):

cannot, you should put it in html or use it by npm module

```js
import smtp from 'smtp'
```

Comment: it is not a module.